# chrome.extension.onRequest listener reach original content

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, jsonp

I'm using JSONP in a google chrome extension.
In order to make it work, i had to add

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);
```

and then make the request like this:

```
var jsonpURL;
$(document).ready(function(){
   /* i make the "someurl" here from a div's content */
   jsonpURL="someurl";
   chrome.extension.sendRequest({action:'getJSON',url:jsonpURL});
});
```

in the listener i'd like to hide some div on the page

```
function onRequest(request, sender, callback) {
    if (request.action == 'getJSON') {
        $.getJSON(request.url, function(data){
                // HIDE SOME DIV
        });
    }    
}
```

the question:

how can i reach the original page's content in the `onRequest` function? or if i cant at all, how can i hide some divs depending on the result of request?
i tried jquery selectors and figured out that i reach the bg.htlm, and not the original page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) to page you'd like to modify after JSONP request returns. This script will be able to modify the DOM of the page it was injected to. After content script is in place you can communicate between background page and content script using messages. So basically, what you need to do is to [send a message](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) 'ok jsonp retured!' whenever background event listener `onRequest` is fired. After content script receives this message it can modify the DOM.

Even simpler option (but more limited) is to use a [Programmatic injection](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi) of javascript to some page.

Comment: thanks for the help, it works just great :)
thanks to you i make some more research.
I started developing extensions yesterday, learned jsonp and some more javascript, and my code was like waaaat?
I made the request from content script and couldn't realy understand what i'm doing :D
Now it makes sense! content scripts gets the info->message to background page -> from the info makes the jsonp -> at the callback process the info -> respond back to content script -> makes the changes on page!!!!!!!!!! thanks :)